# Incorrect use of the partitive?

Tags: partitif

I am reading the book "Petit Pays," and I've come across the following sentence:

"Maman lui rétorquait que ses enfants étaient **des petits Français**, qu'il ne fallait pas nous ennuyer avec leurs histoires de Rwandais."

As I understand it, when using the partitive with a plural noun...

- you change "de" to "des," unless,
- there is an adjective before the noun

I'm wondering why the sentence uses the phrase "**des petits Français**" instead of "**de petits Français**?" Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is found [here](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-11349.php) : when the adjective and the noun form a sort of compound noun (jeunes hommes, petits joueurs, petits garçons…) there is no change. That's the case for  « petit français » which means "young people from France (children before puberty, adolescents)"; otherwise, were we to write "de petits français" we'd be sayind "french people with a short stature".